# Whats this widget name?

Tags: android

Does anyone know how the widget is called which lets you choose a ringtone in android? The widget looks like a `ListView` and appears on another widget and you can select different items on it?

Like [this one](http://cdn.appstorm.net/android.appstorm.net/files/2011/04/DefaultCustomRingtones.png):

[image]

Is it a `ListView` or not? I need something like this in my activity that appears on other widgets (not in other activity or below of widgets).thanks.

Comment: `AlertDialog` with `ListAdapter` setted ...

Comment: fixed grammar / made it more clear.